# Adding a Background to certain part of a graphic with nvd3

Tags: javascript, graphics, graph, d3.js, nvd3.js

I' have an already made a Stacked/Group multi bar chart with NVD3 which is working great. I need to add a grey background to some of the places of the graphic to inform something to the user.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you don't want a background for the whole chart. In this case you can always use d3's own insert method selection.insert(name, before) (see the documentation at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert ) to display an svg object at a certain in front / behind certain elements...(I guess it would be behind all the groups from you animation basically).

Comment: Do you have an example of that with http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html ? I've been struggling but I still cannot do this. And yes, I want the background for parts of the chart.